# https traffic appears to be going to root domain and not sub domains

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Ok, I have no good way of trying to logically say this.. so I will try my best to describe it but apologize in advance for doing a poor job.

I have 6 or so sub domains, and recently had a SSL cert installed on my server. All my inbound traffic if using https seems to be going through the main domain, rather than any of the 6 subdomains.

so I have for example:

domain.com - main domain
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.com
sub4.domain.com
sub5.domain.com
sub6.domain.com

if I use https://subX.domain.com (X being a number from above). The files in the subX are not used. I tested this concept by putting a couple seed files in each variation of the domain. All unique and random. So theres no way any one of the domains could have those files.

using any of the 6 subs I get 404's.. however if I use either domain.com or subX.domain.com and a file thats only in domain.com example: domain.com has iiiindext25.html but none of the subs do..

If I do https://subX.domain.com/iiiindext25.html I see that file, if I do http://subX.domain.com/iiiindext25.html I don't see that file, I see the 404 error I would expect.

if I do http://subX.domain.com/ any of the files I put in any one respectively I see the file.

So overall It appears anytime https:// is in play all traffic gets routed to the main domain. Which I don't picture being proper behavior. Any suggestions or ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: One this is missing here Chris, What is your webserver IIS/Apache or Nginx etc.. ? and your SSL certificate is wildcard?

Comment: Apache, and no I don't think it was a wildcard (not this cert, one in the future is planned but not currently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation now, the https is listening on the root folder, I'm not fully familiar with Apache but all web servers think the same. Can you try to check the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf You will see which folder is asigned by default.

Now you can edit your Virtual host and add

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subX.example.com
    DocumentRoot /yoursite/www

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/subX.example.com.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

but remember if the certificate is not wildcard you will get the **The site's security certificate is not trusted!**

And restart the apache after changing in the Virtual host